# PHP: Save large numbers in excel as it is

Tags: php, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I created a report. When exported in the excel or csv, the contact number fields gets converted with the "+" sign. Well thats not a problem when clicked on the fields. As it shows the actual number on click. But when I imported it to the Google contact the field didn't change. The contact was uploaded along with the plus sign.

[image]

How do I solve this problem. Please let me know if there is any solution or you guys need further explanation.

**Google Contact:** 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Either set the value explicitly as a string, or set a number format mask for the cell that forces display of all digits (e.g. '#,##0' 0r '0') rather than default format.**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '1234567890', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```